# how to hide bottom bar of android (back, home) in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I hide the bottom android bar (back button, home button) permanently in xamarin forms? I tried some code but its hiding it temporarily. When I touch the screen, it again shows. But I want to hide it completely.

Comment: I don't think you can, or you should, those buttons are trivial to navigating within the OS!

Comment: trivial means of little importance, I think you mean the opposite @GeraldVersluis

Comment: Maybe you **should look** at **this**: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129571/is-there-a-way-for-activity-to-hide-the-bottom-navigation-bar

Comment: From the link I provided, it seems you **can** hide it, but **not permanently.** Once the user clicks on the screen, it will re-appear. (And **should** disappear when the user leaves the screen **alone.**)

Answer (score 28):

I appreciate I'm rather late to the party with this answer, but I thought I'd chuck this in here for anyone else who's had the torrid time I've had trying to figure this out.

My Droid MainActivity now looks like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    //====================================
    int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;

    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;

    Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
    //====================================

    LoadApplication(new Pages.App());
}
```

That bit between the commented equals is the sweet spot. Ideally it also needs to be called in the overriden OnStart and OnResume methods as well as OnCreate, to ensure the flags remain set.

If you use "Immersive" rather than "ImmersiveSticky" for that last flag it'll make the top status and bottom system nav bars disappear as required, but when they reappear (from dragging down at the top of the screen, for instance) the bottom one won't disappear again. Therefore using "ImmersiveSticky" is the kiddie.

Comment: FYI: for me, I had to add the code between the equals comments *after* the LoadApplication call for it to work. This is true for my Android 6.0 emulator as well as my Moto e4 phone running Android 7.1.1.

Comment: @Code4aliving Very curious, I'm running emulators for both those versions and that isn't the case for me. I won't attempt to understand why; Xamarin is a particularly arcane beast.

Comment: @Code4aliving  I have tried above code for my xamarin.forms project.
But that's now working for me. My project is for kindle tab and in landscape mode. Can you help me out this?

Comment: @Vivek Shah, please try this: in main activity, override OnWindowFocusChanged() and put in this logic:

int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;

Comment: @Code4aliving, actually the main code was not working because I have used Acr.UserDialogs loading indicator. And once I added OnWindowFocusChanged method, the back button gets hides but only when I run app second time.(On fresh install back button still remains there)

Comment: I've tried NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); and in XAML: NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" + plethora of other hints but none of them worked for me axcept of this. Thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately this longer works on the new Samsung phones / OS.

Comment: @Alan2 Some OS "block" this Immersive mode feature, i don't have an Samsung, but in MIUI this happens too, for me, i had to enable the app i wanted in the Fullscreen Mode settings, for me it was: Display > FullscreenMode > Then enable the apps that need to have fullscreen, this should do the trick, but i belive there is something that flags an app has an fullscreen app, since someapps come with this already enabled, once i figure it out i let you know, but this should help you debuging your stuff

Comment: This works at the beginning, but if I click on an entry or a picker the bottom navigation bar comes back.  I have this code in the OnCreate, OnResume, OnStart, andOnWindowFocusChanged and still doesn't go away. Any ideas?

Comment: @SteveLobdell have you got the flag "ImmersiveSticky", not just "Immersive"?

Comment: Yes I have it set to ImmersiveSticky @DrObey

Comment: @SteveLobdell, are you using an unusual Android variant with this, as some of the 'quirky' custom variants can work in different ways that aren't standard, and thus the proper techniques like this don't always work (I typically think Samsung, as their Android variants are hugely customised).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the status and navigation bar, you just set:

Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Visible;

It's working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Also, as [Ricardo Dias Morais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248138/how-to-hide-bottom-bar-of-android-back-home-in-xamarin-forms#comment106388756_42088471) said,

> Some OS "block" this Immersive mode feature, i don't have an Samsung, but in MIUI this happens too, for me, i had to enable the app i wanted in the Fullscreen Mode settings, for me it was: Display > FullscreenMode > Then enable the apps that need to have fullscreen

I can provide more information if it is required :)

Comment: Whoa, seeing that my comment got the reward is amazing to see :D

Comment: I rather not steal answers :D And you deserved it!

Comment: yeah, the person who made the bounty didn't message me or anything that what I commented worked, it's not your fault, you did well mentioned me, most people don't